Springboot javax Predicates with JSON array
I've the table "vwt" in the database with a json column, named "tasks". The "tasks" column is structured like this:
[
    {
        "data":{
            "submission":{
                "codice": 123
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "data": {
            "submission": {
                "pool": "abc"
            }
        }
    }
]

With this query I'm able to select the records with a specific value of tasks[].data.sumbmission.codice
SELECT * 
FROM vwt, json_array_elements(vwt.tasks) as obj
WHERE obj->'data'->'submission'->>'codice' = 123

Is there a way to recreate this query using the javax Predicates?
Thank you
